# Not able to find total and averages for the given number - Correct Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to create a loop that adds the 4 charges together and then average the charges so the customer knows their average item charge. Even I want to create a statement to find the average. Display the average with a label and format number with dollar sign and two decimal places.

When I run this code I in the total variable only last value from the myCharges is displayed. I want the total and the average.
For the average i need help to print with 2 decimal places.

```
double[] myCharges = {12,13,14,15.55} ;
 double total = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < myCharges.Length; i++)
 {
     total += myCharges[i];
 }
  Console.WriteLine("Total of MyCharges are {0:C}", total);
  Console.WriteLine("Average of MyCharges are {0:C}", myCharges.Average().ToString("0.00));
  Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the value of total every loop.  You'll want to do this (note the + sign):

```
total += myCharges[i];
```

Alternatively you can skip the loop and use:

```
myCharges.Sum();
```

To get 2 decimal places you can do this:

```
myCharges.Average().ToString("0.00");
```

Comment: The currency string he is using also will do 2 decimal places, as would using "F2" for a non-currency format string.

Comment: Ahh, Ok. I don't usually format my strings that way :)

Comment: I believe F2 is the equivalant of "0.00" (perhaps without the leading 0 if the number is less than 0), try putting "F2" instead of "0.00" and see what happens. The format strings are also more "normal" when doing String.Format (which, incidentally, is what Console.Writeline actually calls).

Comment: I have to use for loop and total is suppose to be calculated inside the loop. Total += myCharges[i] is working perfectly fine

Comment: myCharges.Averges().ToString("0.00")) is working perfectly fine

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`Enumerable.Sum()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("Total of MyCharges are {0:C}", myCharges.Sum());
```

Your current code does store only last value of array because of the `total = myCharges[i];` assignment that forgets previous value. You can fix it by using `+=`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCharges.Length; i++)
{
     total += myCharges[i];
}
```

Comment: This works as well, and is harder to mess up than the for loop in the OPs code.

Answer (score 1):

Your 6th line should read

```
total += myCharges[i];
```

Using just = does *assignment* when you want it to sum. Just for clarity, += is the same as saying `total = total + myCharges[i].`

As far as 2 decimal places go, the C (currency) formatting string should take care of it for you. If you don't want the average formatted as currency, try the F2 format string, or one of the others on: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Alexei's answer is a better way to calculate Sum. However, to point out where you're going wrong for educational purposes you can see the line in your code:

```
total = myCharges[i];
```

only holds the current value. To fix that change it instead to:

```
total += myCharges[i];
```

But really, using the built-in functionality is simpler.